# NSSlider labels

Tags: cocoa, label, nsslider

ALL,

I couldn't find anything in the Cocoa documentation about making labels for some NSSlider values. Is this functionality does not exist or I am missing something?

If this is not exist how do place the labels for the vertically placed NSSlider control with the ticks placed on the left side of the control?

Answer (score -2):

Normally a slider is linked to a text field which indicates the current numerical value. You will just have to position labels as best as you can.

Comment: Have any idea on how to do that for the vertically aligned control?